# How to upload the payload for a post request randomly in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

Have the following scenario, in my JSON response there is a value called `visit` which can have either 1 or more than 1 element. So, if the `visit` have 1 element then the default payload should be sent next POST request or if the `visit` have more than 1 element then I'm fetching a random value and want to update the payload and sent to the next POST request.

Let me elaborate,

**Condition 1** [Have 1 element in the visit section]

[image]

**Condition 2** [Have more than 1 element in the visit section]

[image]

**JSON Response for Condition 1**

```
{"studyDTO":{"studyId":191,"studyCode":"test_ispptest2"},"sites":[{"studyId":191,"siteRecid":201,"siteId":"20000"}],"subjects":[{"studyId":191,"siteRecid":201,"subjectRecid":245,"subjectNumber":"20002"}],"states":null,"allVisits":true,"modalities":null,"examDates":null,"series":null,"transferType":null,"sftpLocations":[],"dicomLocations":[],"fileSystemLocations":[],"rawFileSystemLocations":[],"customFolder":null,"folderStructure":null,"customFile":null,"fileStructure":null,"includePS":null}
```

**JSON Response for Condition 2**

```
{"studyDTO":{"studyId":191,"studyCode":"test_ispptest2"},"sites":[{"studyId":191,"siteRecid":16521,"siteId":"11001"}],"subjects":[],"visits":[{"studyId":191,"visitSubmitName":"baseline","visitDisplayName":"Baseline","orderOfDisplay":10},{"studyId":191,"visitSubmitName":"cycle_1","visitDisplayName":"Cycle 1","orderOfDisplay":20}],"sftpLocations":[],"dicomLocations":[],"fileSystemLocations":[],"rawFileSystemLocations":[],"states":null,"modalities":null,"examDates":null,"series":null,"transferType":null,"customFolder":false,"customFile":false,"folderStructure":null,"fileStructure":null,"allSites":false,"allSubjects":true,"allVisits":false,"allStates":false,"allExamDates":false,"allModalities":false,"allSeries":false,"softEditOverride":false,"includePS":false,"includeSR":false,"includeRTStruct":false,"dicomTemplate":null,"errorMessage":null,"successMessage":null}
```

When I am in Condition 2, fetching random `visitSubmitName`,`visitDisplayName`,`orderOfDisplay` and updating in the payload.

**Payload for condition 1:**

```
{"studyDTO":{"studyId":191,"studyCode":"test_ispptest2"},"sites":[{"studyId":191,"siteRecid":201,"siteId":"20000"}],"subjects":[{"studyId":191,"siteRecid":201,"subjectRecid":245,"subjectNumber":"20002"}],"states":null,"allVisits":true,"modalities":null,"examDates":null,"series":null,"transferType":null,"sftpLocations":[],"dicomLocations":[],"fileSystemLocations":[],"rawFileSystemLocations":[],"customFolder":null,"folderStructure":null,"customFile":null,"fileStructure":null,"includePS":null}
```

**Payload for condition 2:**

```
{"studyDTO":{"studyId":191,"studyCode":"test_ispptest2"},"sites":[{"studyId":191,"siteRecid":16521,"siteId":"11001"}],"allSubjects":true,"states":null,"visits":[{"studyId":191,"visitSubmitName":"baseline","visitDisplayName":"Baseline","orderOfDisplay":10}],"modalities":null,"examDates":null,"series":null,"transferType":null,"sftpLocations":[],"dicomLocations":[],"fileSystemLocations":[],"rawFileSystemLocations":[],"customFolder":null,"folderStructure":null,"customFile":null,"fileStructure":null,"includePS":null}
```

Only change in the payload from condition 1 is,

[image]

Solution I have tried so far is created a JSR223 post processer with the following code:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
Random rnd = new Random();
def jsonString = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
def jsonConvert = new JsonSlurper();
def object = jsonConvert.parseText(jsonString);
def studyCode = object.studyDTO.studyCode;
def visitS = object.visits.size().toString();
def visitSize = visitS?.isInteger() ? visitS.toInteger() : null
def visitNUM = rnd.nextInt(visitSize);
//def defaultPayload = "{"studyDTO":{"studyId":${studyID},"studyCode":"${study_name}"},"sites":[{"studyId":${studyID},"siteRecid":${siteRecID},"siteId":"${siteID}"}],"subjects":[{"studyId":${studyID},"siteRecid":${siteRecID},"subjectRecid":${subjectRecID},"subjectNumber":"${subjectNumber}"}],"states":null,"allVisits":true,"modalities":null,"examDates":null,"series":null,"transferType":null,"sftpLocations":[],"dicomLocations":[],"fileSystemLocations":[],"rawFileSystemLocations":[],"customFolder":null,"folderStructure":null,"customFile":null,"fileStructure":null,"includePS":null}"

if (visitSize>1) {
    def visitSubmitName = object.visits[visitNUM].visitSubmitName
    def visitDisplayName = object.visits[visitNUM].visitDisplayName
    def orderOfDisplay= object.visits[visitNUM].orderOfDisplay.toString();
    //Change the payload with the three value 
    
    vars.put('payload',updatedPayload )
}
else {
    vars.put('payload',defaultPayload )
}
```

And the next post sampler,

[image]

Error details:

1. Getting error with the `defaultPayload` declaration and need the logic for updating the payload.
2. Is the post sampler declared correctly?

Thanks, in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You either need to [escape](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_escaping_special_characters) every quotation mark with a backslash

   ```
   def defaultPayload = "def defaultPayload = '{\"studyDTO\":{\"studyId\":191,\"studyCode\":\"test_ispptest2\"},\"sites\":[{\"studyId\":191,\"siteRecid\":201,\"siteId\":\"20000\"}],\"subjects\":[{\"studyId\":191,\"siteRecid\":201,\"subjectRecid\":245,\"subjectNumber\":\"20002\"}],\"states\":null,\"allVisits\":true,\"modalities\":null,\"examDates\":null,\"series\":null,\"transferType\":null,\"sftpLocations\":[],\"dicomLocations\":[],\"fileSystemLocations\":[],\"rawFileSystemLocations\":[],\"customFolder\":null,\"folderStructure\":null,\"customFile\":null,\"fileStructure\":null,\"includePS\":null}'"
   ```

   or use single quotation marks instead:

   ```
   def defaultPayload = '{"studyDTO":{"studyId":191,"studyCode":"test_ispptest2"},"sites":[{"studyId":191,"siteRecid":201,"siteId":"20000"}],"subjects":[{"studyId":191,"siteRecid":201,"subjectRecid":245,"subjectNumber":"20002"}],"states":null,"allVisits":true,"modalities":null,"examDates":null,"series":null,"transferType":null,"sftpLocations":[],"dicomLocations":[],"fileSystemLocations":[],"rawFileSystemLocations":[],"customFolder":null,"folderStructure":null,"customFile":null,"fileStructure":null,"includePS":null}'
   ```
2. No, you either need to use just `${payload}` or if you prefer coding go for [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) like `${__groovy(vars.get('payload'),)}`

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html)
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Answer (score 1):

Guess Dmitri has solved your issue, now coming to the logic. Before that, if I checked your payload for the post request are different. Please try the below code in your JSR223 post-processer.

The json update could be done through `json.builder`

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder

Random rnd = new Random();
def jsonString = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
def jsonConvert = new JsonSlurper();
def object = jsonConvert.parseText(jsonString);
def studyCode = object.studyDTO.studyCode;
def visitS = object.visits.size().toString();
def visitSize = visitS?.isInteger() ? visitS.toInteger() : null
def visitNUM = rnd.nextInt(visitSize);

def defaultPayload = '{"studyDTO":{"studyId":${studyID},"studyCode":"${study_name}"},"sites":[{"studyId":${studyID},"siteRecid":${siteRecID},"siteId":"${siteID}"}],"subjects":[{"studyId":${studyID},"siteRecid":${siteRecID},"subjectRecid":${subjectRecID},"subjectNumber":"${subjectNumber}"}],"states":null,"allVisits":true,"modalities":null,"examDates":null,"series":null,"transferType":null,"sftpLocations":[],"dicomLocations":[],"fileSystemLocations":[],"rawFileSystemLocations":[],"customFolder":null,"folderStructure":null,"customFile":null,"fileStructure":null,"includePS":null}';

def updatedPayLoad = "";
if (visitSize>1) {
    def visitSubmitNameR = object.visits[visitNUM].visitSubmitName
    def visitDisplayNameR = object.visits[visitNUM].visitDisplayName
    def orderOfDisplayR = object.visits[visitNUM].orderOfDisplay.toString();
    def newORDEROFDIS = orderOfDisplayR?.isInteger() ? orderOfDisplayR.toInteger() : null
    updatedPayLoad = '{"studyDTO":{"studyId":${studyID},"studyCode":"${study_name}"},"sites":[{"studyId":${studyID},"siteRecid":${siteRecID},"siteId":"${siteID}"}],"allSubjects":true,"states":null,"visits":[{"studyId":${studyID},"visitSubmitName":"","visitDisplayName":"","orderOfDisplay":00}],"modalities":null,"examDates":null,"series":null,"transferType":null,"sftpLocations":[],"dicomLocations":[],"fileSystemLocations":[],"rawFileSystemLocations":[],"customFolder":null,"folderStructure":null,"customFile":null,"fileStructure":null,"includePS":null}'
    def newUpdatedPayLoad = jsonConvert.parseText(updatedPayLoad);
    def jsonBuilder = new JsonBuilder(newUpdatedPayLoad)
    jsonBuilder.content.visits[0].visitSubmitName = visitSubmitNameR
    jsonBuilder.content.visits[0].visitDisplayName = visitDisplayNameR
    jsonBuilder.content.visits[0].orderOfDisplay = newORDEROFDIS
    vars.put('finalPayLoad',jsonBuilder.toPrettyString())
}
else {
    vars.put('finalPayLoad',defaultPayload)
}
```